# Simple C++ WebSocket Client (draft 08+ compatible)?

Tags: c++, websocket

I have been trying to find a simple C++ WebSocket client that is draft 08+ compatible. I have been able to find some server implementations, but that is not what I need. I need a client, hopefully with no extra stuff like server implementation to keep it small and clean and easy to build with as less dependencies as possible.

It has to be 08+ version compatible (Firefox 6+, Chrome 14+).

Do I need to implement it myself or have I missed a great library?