# Websocket Client in C++

Tags: c++, c, websocket

I need to implement a websocket client using c++. I have already created a basic websocket server using ruby. But now I want to test the connection using c/c++. Is there any easy to use libraries available to implement websockets in c/c++ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Damn, I hate it when people write _C/C++_, make up your mind, are you using _C_ or _C++_ ? There are **not** the same language.

Comment: I agree with you.. but client is asking demo in either of c or c++ . Sorry for that. :-)

Comment: C/C++ is a sensible thing to ask for if one is writing in C++, as you can straightforwardly use a C API from C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are boost::asio and Poco.Net and probably a few others, but the C-API berkeley sockets aren't that hard, so if you don't want to use those libraries take a look at them.

Edit: Sorry, I probably got you wrong with "websockets". Did you look here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations
(Taken from [Simple C++ WebSocket Client (draft 08+ compatible)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468354/simple-c-websocket-client-draft-08-compatible))

Comment: Currently looking into it. And i found websocket++ useful for my implementation. I hope it will work. Thanks :-)

Comment: +1 for going with websocket++: it's very conformant to spec (final RFC6455) and high performance. and ASIO based.

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia link doesn't list any browser-external client libraries based on C or C++ as of 2013-03-21. The mentioned "websocket++" library is not on the Wikipedia list, for example.

Comment: @JonWatte the Wikipedia list was recently pruned to list only browsers and major web frameworks, so lots of the websocket-only are no longer listed. In general the list is no longer comprehensive or useful for the purposes of finding libraries with specific features or requirements.

Comment: It looks like Wikipedia has restored the list of libraries. It is listing websocket++ and others once again.

Answer (score 10):

There's a great library here, Beast.WebSocket which builds heavily on Boost.Asio:
http://vinniefalco.github.io/

Here's an example program that talks websocket:

```
#include <beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <beast/buffers_debug.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "echo.websocket.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "80"}));

    using namespace beast::websocket;

    // WebSocket connect and send message using beast
    stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> ws(sock);
    ws.handshake(host, "/");
    ws.write(boost::asio::buffer("Hello, world!"));

    // Receive WebSocket message, print and close using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    opcode op;
    ws.read(op, sb);
    ws.close(close_code::normal);
    std::cout <<
        beast::debug::buffers_to_string(sb.data()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: i have Boost version: 1.53.0, and i am getting fatal error: boost/beast/websocket.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: You need Boost 1.58.0 or later, and you have to add the beast/include directory to your include paths.

Comment: i download latest boost and cant find beast in it, anyways i downloaded boost and beast and tried compiling my code and got many errors, so now testing with easywsclient, but will try this library tomorrow. idk what went wrong, it said some .hpp file is missing ill post full error tomorrow, there should be step by step, on how to run WebSocket Client. thanks

Comment: [root@cpptests]# g++ websocket1.cpp -o websocket1boost -I /usr/src/beast/include  -l boost_system
In file included from /usr/src/beast/include/boost/beast.hpp:13:0,
                 from websocket1.cpp:1:
/usr/src/beast/include/boost/beast/config.hpp:15:40: fatal error: boost/core/ignore_unused.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/core/ignore_unused.hpp>

Answer (score 9):

Websocket++ should do it foryou. https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp

although knowing what versions of Websocket the server/client implement are important.

Comment: It seems that Websocket++ is not being actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it still can be useful.

There is a good websocket library developed for in C.
There are a few examples of how you can create a websocket and handle it.

http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets (for more details) or
https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets