# (Win32) Connecting with wss ( websocket secure) using socket

Tags: sockets, winapi, https, websocket

In my Win32 application, I am trying to connect with websocket(ws://localhost:3000) using socket is as follows,

```
 std:string reqLine = "GET /default HTTP/1.1\r\n"             // Request line
 std::string header =  "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                       "Sec-WebSocket-Key: GCeEn+pBGdrdj4mcrtBukA==\r\n" 
                       "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
                       "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                       "\r\n";

std::string req = reqLine + header;
::send(m_socket, req, req.size());

Inturn, I am getting response as follows,
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 4W7fNwDGO1aKNr50PzdRDJaYIGE=
```

this works fine.

Now, I want to connect with websocket secure (wss://localhost:443) using socket. What would be the request line and header in this case.

Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Websocket Client in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528811/websocket-client-in-c)

Comment: See duplicate. You really don't want to write a websocket or HTTP client yourself.